# Open .xls file in ionic in app browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a base 64 string converted from a .xls document.I want to open the .xls file in the ionic in-app browser.Is there a way to achieve this?The code is working fine for the pdf format but it gives the "Load Error" in case of .xls

Comment: Did you find any solution?